# Parsing xml document in java

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to retrieve some data from xml document, but the program throws NullPointerException. This is the snippet of code:

```
     if("Success".equals(nodeValue))
     {

           NodeList productList = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("Products").item(0).getChildNodes(); // gets all childs of Product node
           for (int j = 0; j < productList.getLength(); j++)
           {
               singleProduct = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("Product").item(j).getChildNodes();

               for(int x = 0; x < singleProduct.getLength(); x++)
               {  
                   if(singleProduct.item(x).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                   {
                   String nodeName = singleProduct.item(x).getNodeName();

                 String value = singleProduct.item(x).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                         System.err.println(x+" "+nodeName+" "+ value);
                     if ("ProductID".equals(nodeName))
                {

                    id.put(xx, value);
                        type.put(y, singleProduct.item(x).getChildNodes().item(1).getAttributes().getNamedItem("type").getTextContent());;
                    xx++;
                        y++;
                     }
                  }
               }
           }
     }
```

This part throws exception:

```
                 String value = singleProduct.item(x).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
```

Exception is thrown due to the value of index inside item(0) method. How should I know the index of item in collection? I have similar program parsing XML document, it throws exception (NullPOinter) but still it runs because I catch exception. The same thing I am trying to do here, but the program does not work, terminates, though I catch Exception.
How to extract correct index for item() method?
Cheers

Answer (score 4):

```
getChildNodes().item(0)
```

[`getChildNodes()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getChildNodes%28%29) returns a `NodeList`; use this value and check that its [length](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html#getLength%28%29) is greater than zero.

`NullPointerException`s are an indication of a programming error and should not be caught.

---

As an aside, you may want to look at the [XPath API](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi.html) for extracting data from DOM trees.

Comment: I checked the length, it is 1. What are other thoughts?

Comment: @ucas - it isn't obvious to me where the issue is based on the code sample. I can see some red flags - like calling `xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName` more than once, but without seeing a sample document and the ultimate goal, it is difficult to provide help.